# Any way to tell where log output is coming from?

Tags: logs, tail

On a unix system, I have a file in `/logs` which is being written to constantly by multiple sources. Is there a way, maybe with `tail`(?), to determine what processes are writing to this output?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the program called `lsof`.

Comment: hmmm.. when I type lsof <log name> it just gives me 'java' and the log name.

Comment: yes that's the process writing to that file